# MVC Model if clause in HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

i want to filter my model due to isUpload variable in Model.

My logic is if Models.Docs item's isupload variable =true i want to show button has 'Sil' text.Otherwise if isUpload variable=false i want to show button has 'Görsel Yükle text.How can i supply this ?

i make model foreach if clause to View.Everything okey Model.Docs filtered for isUpload bool.
My code is here :

```
@if (Model.Data != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.Data)
    {
        <table cellspacing="20" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle">
                    <span>@item.doctype_desc</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (Model.Docs != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item2 in Model.Docs)
                        {
                            <input class="uploadInput" id="@item.doctype_id" data-doctypeid="@item.doctype_id" style="display: none;" type="file" accept="image/* ">
                            if (item2.isUpload)
                            {
                                <input class="uploadButton" id="btnSave" type="button" value="Sil" data-doctypeid="@item.doctype_id" />
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <input class="uploadButton" id="btnSave" type="button" value="Görsel Yükle" data-doctypeid="@item.doctype_id" />    
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
}
```

And this is my model if logic i debugged its correct return to model.

Details of Controlller Syntax :

```
  //formData.Docs variable is my returned data from database.
 // formTypes.Data is including all types of formdata.
  foreach (var item in formData.Docs)
  {

if (formtypesData.Data.Any(x => x.doctype_id == item.doctype_id))
  {
    item.isUpload = true;
    }
   else
   {
   item.isUpload = false;
    }

      }

    model.Docs = formData.Docs;

    #endregion

    return View(model);
```

Comment: And now have you got any button on this column?

Comment: Im using input button type for click input.A screen about uploading images.İf image value has isUpload Showing Delete input button text.Otherwise showing Upload Text.

Comment: I understand it, I'm asking what is result of your code  now?

Comment: Oh sorry.Now, writings Sil(Delete) all of them ....

Comment: Are you sure there is `items` with `isUpload = false`?

Comment: Yes. I debugged them.

Comment: Already there are only 1 isupload available, others are not in model.docs.

Comment: So your problem is with model? Can you share how you declared model and assign value to send view

Comment: I believe your issue is because the temporary variable created for each item in model.Docs is only being altered inside that foreach and not altering the actual model.

Comment: No, it turns out to be logically correct, but I think I'm applying the wrong logic on the view side. @jaredlee.exe

Comment: is it supposed to iterate through the same collection of 'Model.Docs' for each iteration of 'Model.Data'?

Comment: One } is missing on your code? Foreach's }

Comment: No i pasted wrong maybe ?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the `if(item2.isUpload)` does it correctly reflect the values from the controller function and is the Docs collection the same as the controller?

Comment: Can you paste right code that has foreach's end bracket? It needs to solve your problem

Comment: thanks, i fixed my problem , its about for each in controller :). I reduced for each to only one for each in same model.